# L1 norm constraint on product of 2 matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, normed-spaces, matrix-decomposition, non-convex-optimization

I want to solve below minimization problem

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{A, B}{\text{minimize}}
& & ||Y-AB^T -D||_F^2 \\
& \text{subject to}
&& |A_i|_1 \leq a, \; i = 1, \ldots, k \\
&&& |B_j|_1 \leq a, \; j = 1, \ldots, k \\
&&& |(AB^T)_k|_1 \leq b, \; k = 1, \ldots, n
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $Y \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$, $A \in \mathbb{R^{n\times k}}$ ,$B \in \mathbb{R^{n \times k}}$, $D \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$ is a diagonal matrix, $||_{1}$ denotes $l_1$ norm, $A_i$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $A$ matrix and $k < n$. I thought of solving this minimization problem using Proximal Alternating Learnized Minimization (PALM), but I am not sure about how to include $|(AB^T)_k|_1 \leq a$ constraint in the minimization algorithm. Is there any other way to solve this minimization i.e. without using PALM? I had posted the question on MathOverflow also, here is the link of it https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299843/l1-norm-constraint-on-product-of-2-matrix

Comment: Wasn't this posted also on MathOverflow?

Comment: I posted on MathOverflow as I wasn't able to find a solution here.

Comment: Link one to the other.

Comment: I am not sure how to link one to the other. I would be really grateful if you could please provide some reference for it?

Comment: You have already linked from here to MO. Now post a link on the MO question to here.